# How to create decorator for roles with Flask-Login

Tags: decorator, roles, flask-login

I can't find the best solution in 2023 for my project without flask-security or principal because their security is in question + they have no proper updates for py.

I use Flask-Login and want to make decorators for addresses of admin pages.

now I use simplify model for my routes like

```
if current_user.roles == 'admin': 
   la = la
   return render_template("admin/admin_dashboard.html", la=la)
else:
   return redirect(url_for('views.index'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I have to create a function with wraps where user if not authenticated or not admin redirected to somewhere (login for example)